# Задание переменной по пользовательской формуле c++

Tags: c++

Задача состоит следующая: 
Нужно задать переменную `f(x)` таким образом, чтобы пользователь вводил формулу для её расчета (неважно, в консоли или в файле). 
К примеру пользователь ввел `sin(x) => f(x) = sin(x)`
 (Переменная x задана в программе).

Слышал, что что-то подобное можно провернуть через векторы, но варианты реализации не приходят в голову, если у кого есть шаблоны, прошу поделиться.

Логика программы следующая:
1.**Читаем файл и находим формулу sin(x)**
2.**Создаем переменную типа char fun[]="sin(x)"**
3.**Неизвестным образом (ВНИМАНИЕ,ЗДЕСЬ И ЗАКЛЮЧАЕТСЯ ВЕСЬ ВОПРОС) преобразовываем код так, чтобы на выходе получить:**

```
double f(double x){
return sin(x);//это и есть наш fun[];
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: В С++ для этого готовых средств нет. Нужно или искать какую-то библиотеку для этого (а-ля https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr), или писать самому.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я так и предполагал, спасибо за библиотеку